# remove subdomain from url PHP

Tags: php

I'm cleaning URL from a text file with a PHP script, here's the code right now :

```
        $file = __DIR__."/url.txt";
        $f = fopen($file, "r");
        $array1 = array();

        while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
            $nl = mb_strtolower($line,'UTF-8');
            $array1[] = $nl;
        }


        foreach ($array1 as $value) {
            $value = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $value);
            $value = preg_replace('#^www.#', '', $value);

            echo $value."<br>";
        }
```

So I remove the `http://` and `www` from these urls

Here's the output :

```
urlnumberone.com
urlnumbertwo.uk
subdomain.urlnumberthree.com
urlnumberfour.com
```

What I want is to remove subdomain too, and just have `urlnumberthree.com`

Thanks for your help !

Comment: maybe str_replace? $value = str_replace('subdomain.', ' ', $value );

Comment: "subdomain" is not unique, there are others urls with subdomains named different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pure regex solution:

```
preg_match('#[^\.]+[\.]{1}[^\.]+$#', $value , $matches);
$value = $matches[0];
```

This replaces both of your `preg_replace`s.

Comment: this work perfectly for me. Much better than the large functions suggested on other posts.

Comment: won't work with .co.uk urls or com.au for example

Comment: @chifliiiii, of course it won't. This is not what OP requested.

Answer (score 2):

Check occurrences of '.' if they are more than 1, remove the beginning until first dot.